# Most efficient way to join three tables - junction table or otherwise?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, relational-database

Say I have 3 tables: **Users**, **Posts** and **Categories**

What is the most efficient way of accessing all Posts in a particular Category for a User?

Is a [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) e.g. **UserPostCategories** the best way? Or is there an alternative and more efficient way to do this?

Here's what I'm basically thinking for the database layout:

**Users**

- id
- username
- password

**Posts**

- id
- post

**Categories**

- id
- name

**UserPostCategories**

- user_id
- post_id
- category_id

This makes it easy to access all Posts in a particular Category for a User OR all Posts for a particular User in all Categories OR list all Categories for a particular User and so forth.

What is the best way to do this when building an app to run in a production/public-facing environment? I say production because **I'm looking for the most efficient solution and not just any old solution.**

Comment: Any other solution than a junction table like you have proposed will likely result in a good chunk of data duplication.

Comment: @Chris yeah - that's what I figured! Hence why I asked in case some wiz bang genius knew something I didn't.

Comment: I think your solution is the fastest/most straightforward, but not the most efficient. I'm assuming that Posts have Categories, and Users do not directly have Categories. For me, I'd have two junction tables - `UsersPosts` and `PostsCategories`. The `JOIN` query is trivial across them, and any query not requiring the third table is automatically more efficient.